# How to get the max/min value of a String[] array?

Tags: java, arrays

I got the idea to check for the max/min value of an array from [here](http://www.java-examples.com/find-largest-and-smallest-number-array-example). It works wonders, but I'm wondering if there's a way to tear the code apart and make it more compact. Maybe there's a command of some sort? I don't know, and that's why I'm asking you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What are you grades this month?\nThey must be seperated by spaces.").split(" ");

    int smallest = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
    int largest = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(input[i]) > largest) { 
           largest = Integer.parseInt(input[i]); 
        }
        else if (Integer.parseInt(input[i]) < smallest) { 
          smallest = Integer.parseInt(input[i]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example will help you simplify your code

```
Integer [] myIntArray = new Integer[]{0, 5, 2, 11};
Arrays.sort(myIntArray);

//Output smallest 
System.out.println(myIntArray[0]);

//Output largest
System.out.println(myIntArray[myIntArray.length - 1]);
```

Comment: That works, but only for the smallest number output. I don't know how, in your mind, the largest number output would work? It just subtracts the number "1" from the inputs' length (i.e. if the input was 13 numbers long, the output of this line: `System.out.println(myIntArray[myIntArray.length - 1])`, would be 12).

Comment: If an array as a length of 13, then the array positions will be comprehended between 0 to 12, hence the length - 1.

Comment: Sorry for the mishap. I overlooked a part of your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is the same as Vasco's, but my code starts with a string array and use Set :

```
String[] gradesAsString = { "12", "14", "8", "43"};
Set<Integer> grades = new HashSet<>(gradesAsString.length);

for(String grade : gradesAsString) {
    grades.add(Integer.parseInt(grade));
}

// Sort the collection and get the first (as min) and last (as max) is better for performance
int max = Collections.max(grades);
int min = Collections.min(grades);
```

This code is not complete, you should catch `NumberFormatException` when you use `Integer.parseInt(str)`

I use Set because you just want to check the min and the max, if you want to do something else, like calculate an average, a List is better of course.